# Why does absolute positioned element is displayed over a static one?

Tags: html, css

I know absolute positioning breaks normal flow but since the order in HTML is absolute element first then static one, I was expecting it to be reflected in the display order too.

```css
.absolute
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

.static
{
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="absolute"></div>
  <div class="static"></div>
</div>
```

The reason I need this is because I want to display a sliding menu (the '.absolute' `div`) which slides from bottom to up and appears like it's coming from the back of the '.static' `div`.
The container `div` will obviously need to have 'overflow: visible'.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Maybe another technique is needed? Like CSS `clip`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the answers above give the adequate explanation to the situation you are facing. Given the problem at hand you can use this solution. Just add `position:relative` to the static div.

```css
.absolute
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

.static
{
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="absolute"></div>
  <div class="static"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually no need to add z-index, just change to relative positioning such that the order given by z-index kicks-in  :)

Comment: @DonBox Yeah, I just noticed. I've modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Don, that is precisely the solution I gave you in my answer. The only difference between my answer and this one is that in mine I explain why you need to do it.

Answer (score 8):

As per section [`9.9.1 Specifying the stack level: the 'z-index' property`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#layers) of CSS 2.2:

> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted ***in back-to-front*** order:
>
> - the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> - the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> - the in-flow, non-inline-level, ***non-positioned descendants***.
> - the non-positioned floats.
> - the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.
> - the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the ***positioned descendants with stack level 0***.
> - the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

Third one in list is `position:static` and 6-th is `position:absolute`. I marked them for you.

---

**Edit, based on your question edits:**

In order to fix your issue (which is what you should have asked in the first place, IMHO) you need to

- apply `position:relative;` to your `.static` div, bringing it to the same level with the `position:absolute` one. (Now the'll both be *position*ed).
- If the one you want on top is not the last in DOM, you also need to give it a positive `z-index`, bigger than it's siblings'. Normally they are rendered *back-to-top*.

Comment: but I didn't specify any z-index :)

Comment: And you think not specifying it makes it cease to exist or apply? All elements have default `z-index`. Without it, the browser wouldn't know where to paint them. The rules above are the ones specifying their order for your use-case. I can't help you more than this. You asked why, I linked the rule that is applying, as it is currently formulated in the specs.

Comment: thanks but you don't need z-index set. As you said, "And you think not specifying it makes it cease to exist or apply?"

Comment: If you don't set `z-index`, last one is rendered on top. I think if I specify it clearly in answer, it will help more people.

Answer (score 3):

Absolute position means you can put such div anywhere, and it won’t affect or be affected by any other element in the flow.

Absolutely positioned element is completly removed from the normal flow.

To obtain the effect you want, you might use `z-index` and `position: relative` and `position: absolute`.