# How can I display my SVG layer on top of my Mapbox map?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mapbox

I am trying to display a Voronoi diagram on top of my Mapbox map. I am able to build both, but somehow the Voronoi loads before the map and then it gets replaced by the map, never displayed on top. Where do I need to call my render function to display it on top?

I tried to add a bunch of listeners to call it. I also tried to use multiple selectors, but it seems that it's rendering at the right place, just not at the right time.

My code is here:
https://beta.observablehq.com/@elxavicio/voronoi-of-spains-train-statitions

The voronoi diagram should show on top of the map.

Comment: You create an svg for each rerender. You *really* should fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map has `position: absolute`, and thus is rendered over svg, which is statically positioned. Take a look here [Why does absolute positioned element is displayed over a static one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273135/why-does-absolute-positioned-element-is-displayed-over-a-static-one) . To fix, make svg `position: relative`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really fixed it!